# 13 errors for one line (***) What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java

```
/** 
  * getLargestOfFive method
  * input parameters: int values num1, num2, num3, num4, num5
  * return value    : largest value among 5 input parameters
  */


import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestOfFive2{

  public static void main(String[] args){



    ***public static int getLargestOfFive(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5, int largest){***



      largest = num1; 

      if (num2 > largest){
        largest = num2;
      }
      if (num3 > largest){
        largest = num3;
      }
      if (num4 > largest){
        largest = num4;
      }
      if (num5 > largest){
        largest = num5;

      }

      return largest;


    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where exactly are you getting errors?

Comment: Why on earth did you surround your method declaration with "***"s?  Delete them.  Also, you cannot nest method declarations like that in Java.

Comment: Also you put a function (getLargestOfFive) within another function (main)

Comment: You can't define a method inside a method (unless you use an anonymous class).

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 public static int getLargestOfFive(int agumentsHere){ // method inside method?
 }
}
```

You can't have nested methods in `Java`. Re arrange your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  // call your method from main 
  // eg
   int val=getLargestOfFive(arguments);
}
public static int getLargestOfFive(int agumentsHere){ 
}
```

Read the `Java` doc about [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you're getting so many errors is most likely that you've put a method inside a method. You can't include `getLargestOfFive` in your `main()` method - there's no such thing as nested methods in Java. Rather, separate your methods like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

}

public static int getLargestOfFive(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4 ...)
{

}
```

Note also that you're doing some strange stuff in terms of assigning variables. There's no point in passing `largest` to your method. Rather, define and assign it at the beginning of your function like so:

```
public static int getLargestOfFive(...)
{
    int largest = num1;
}
```

There's no reason to require users to pass a useless variable into your function.

Lastly, the way you're implementing this function is pretty single-purpose. If you wanted, you could pass an iterable to the function, and iterate through it within the method, and you'd be able to ascertain the largest value of *any* number of values. As it stands, this works if and only if the user has five values they want to check.